# How to populate a queue from preloaded data with variable length sequences?

Tags: tensorflow

Say I have input data with variable length sequences loaded into memory:

```
sentences = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
]
```

How can I use this to fill a queue? E.g. something like:

```
padding_q = tf.PaddingFIFOQueue(
    capacity=len(sentences),
    dtypes=[tf.int32], shapes=[[None]])
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(padding_q, [the_wanted_op])
```

How does `the_wanted_op` look like? It should enqueue one sentence yet four enqueues must have enqueued each sentence once.